Female seeking out young male at attacking
I have 7 cats and have for 5 years they all got along. My one female got pregnant before I had her fixed so I sent her to foster care when she was ready to birth and she stayed with her babies for 12 weeks . When she came home she immediately zoned in on one of the young males and attacked him ,he hid in my closet.He was so scared I had to feed him in there put a litter box in there and it was a good 2 month before he came out . She didn't at attack him again for a few weeks but now she did it again and pretty bad .. how do I stop this?

Have you had her fixed since she had the kittens?

Additional to keshlam's question, did you properly reintroduce them? The female was away for three months; that's a long time in a cat's life.
